# Trace of the product of a rank-one and an indefinite matrix, subject to semidefinite constraints

Tags: trace, matrix-rank, semidefinite-programming

Let $Q$ be a Hermitian (indefinite) matrix. Is it true that
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{tr}(QX)\geq0
\quad\text{and}\quad 
X-xx^T\succeq0
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\operatorname{tr}(QX)
\overset{?}{\geq} x^TQx=\operatorname{tr}(Qxx^T) 
\overset{?}{\geq} 0
\end{equation}
In my case $Q$ is usually not full-rank. In fact, the most interesting case is when it is of rank 2, with exactly one positive and one negative eigenvalue (independent of the problem size).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both inequalities are not true in general.

Example: take $X=I$ (identity) and denote $\lambda_+>0$ and $\lambda_-<0$ the positive and the negative eigenvalues of $Q$, respectively. Assume $\lambda_++\lambda_-\ge 0$. Then $I-xx^T\succeq0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\|x\|\le 1$ and we have
\begin{align}
\text{tr}(QX)&=\text{tr}(Q)=\lambda_++\lambda_-\ge0,\\
\text{tr}(Qx^Tx)&=x^TQx.
\end{align}
Choosing $x_\pm$ as normalized eigenvectors for $Q$ with $\lambda_\pm$ gives

- $x_+^TQx_+=\lambda_+>\lambda_++\lambda_-$ which contradicts the first inequality.
- ${x_-}^TQx_-=\lambda_-<0$ which contradicts the second inequality.

Comment: Thanks, very clear. That makes a lot of sense.